# Configuring Open Virtual Network in Ovirt. (OVN)

Tags: virtualization, ovirt

I have 3 hosts with installing ovirt environment. And one host has vm with ovirt-engine, that managing all this system. 
When I tried to setup network to one of my virtual machine in this cluster, i got a problem, that you can see below.

[image]

What is causing this failure, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm new here, I cant add a comment, so I have to answer.

Did you check your network devices of the VM? Are they up and running? It say "No such device" Did you check your network settings in the UI?